# GLTF import animation problem

Tags: animation, nla-editor, gltf

I'm trying to import a GLTF with one animation track:

https://pastebin.com/raw/LxMeuJ32

it displays correctly on several GLTF viewers, e.g. [BabylonJS Sandbox](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com), [three.js GLTF viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com), i.e. the cube should fall on the floor and bounce.

When imported in Blender, all the objects move together.
I also don't understand the content of the non linear animation tracks, as it shows 3 tracks for each object, whereas there are only two channels (position and rotation) animating each object.